# How to find the crossing number of a hypercube Q4?

Tags: graph-theory, hypergraphs

I'm struggling to find the crossing number of Q4, I think I have trouble visualizing the cube and finding the crossing number. Any idea what theorem or lemma I can use?

Comment: It is mentioned in http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/the_crossing_number_of_the_hypercube and https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~mohar/Problems/P3CrossingNumberQd.html that the crossing number of $Q_4$ is $8$. Maybe you can look at the references in the links to see if you can find the proof of this fact.

Answer (score -1):

The Crossing number of Hypercube Q4 is 8.

Q4 can be constructed using two disjoint Q3 which is having a crossing number of 0, by adding an edge from each vertex in one copy of Q3 to the corresponding vertex in the other copy.

The lower bound for the crossing number of Qn is 4n/20 + O(4n/20).

The upper bound for the crossing number of Qn is (165/1024)*(4^n).